# How to estimate probability from frequency?

Tags: probability, statistics, estimation

It might be a simple question, but still difficult for me.

What would be a good way to estimate probability from frequency of occurrence if we have finite number of observations?

**Example.** Some experiment  gives $0$ or $1$, we count experiments where we get $0$ and estimate it probability of $0$ as $p = N_0/N$, where $N$ overall number of experiments.

However in the definition true probability value can be computed having infinite number of experiments, which is impractical.

Is there another(maybe better) way to compute probability in the mentioned example. Or how many experiments $N$ need to be executed so we have some confidence in the estimation?
(Sorry if it doesn't make much sense)

Comment: you used right term: [confidence interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval)

Comment: @farruhota thanks, i should look this up.

Comment: Your choice of $\hat{p}=N_0/N$ perfectly makes sense. And indeed, your question opens up a truly huge area of investigating how well $p$ approximates the true probability and how they help to devise good statistical testing methods. Various estimates pertaining to the former are called under the umbrella term 'concentration inequalities', which themselves easily constitute a rich and vast area of study.

Comment: @SangchulLee, thanks, i try to investigate.